# 32-bit executable running as a 64-bit Windows process?

Tags: .net, windows, visual-studio, x86, 64-bit

I have a project which generates a 32-bit executable. This executable is included as part of a bigger package where the executable is installed as a Windows service using MSI installer. Even though the executable is 32-bit (I examined the file header), the process is running as a 64-bit process. I was trying to debug this process and when I opened the "Attach Process" menu through Visual Studio, I saw its type included x64 instead of x86.

Is this possible or am I missing something? If it is possible, how can I do this for some other 32 bit executable?

Comment: Is this a .NET executable or a native binary?

Comment: @PMF Its a .NET executable.

Comment: .NET executable is exactly like Java or Dalvik applications, they contain bytecodes and run in the VM so obviously they'll be compiled to any native platforms. Those will even run on ARM, RISC-V, PPC... as long as the appropriate VM is available

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For .NET executables, that's normal. .NET executables run in whatever environment suits best, depending on the available hardware and runtime version. It is possible to force executing a .NET executable in 32 bit mode, but that is usually only done when it needs to interact with a 32 bit native dll.

Details differ a bit between .NET Framework assemblies and .NET Core/NET5.0+ assemblies. But for the later, it's basically that the target runtime specifies whether it runs the binary in 32 bit or 64 bit mode. That's now easy, since the application is almost always built in "AnyCPU" mode, telling the runtime that the application doesn't care what CPU is used (or what operating system, hardware, etc.)

Comment: I have 2 versions of this executable, both are 32-bit but one runs as a 64bit Windows service and the other as a 32bit service. Is this because of the way they are built? Probably one used "Any CPU" and the other used some other config?

Comment: That's possible. Are you using .NET Framework or .NET Core?

Comment: I am using .NET Framework

Comment: For .NET Framework, that is built into the code. During compile, you can declare whether you want to run the application in 32 Bit mode or in 64 Bit mode (or decide at runtime). So yes, it's likely the two versions were built with different settings.

Comment: You were right, I was able to make the 2nd 32bit executable run as 64bit process after I changed the build settings. Do you have some document/video where I can read more about these things, specifically for .NET?

Comment: No, I would need to google for that myself. I did have a fight with this for much too long. But nowadays, you can just go for 64 Bit and be done, because 32 Bit Windows is basically dead.